# What's the logic behind this small c++ code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int j=20;
    int i=0;
    for ( int k=0; i<10 && j>10; i++ && j--)
        cout<< "i is " <<i<< " and j is " <<j<<endl;
}
```

So, this is how I see it, first `i` is 0 and `j` is 20, both follows the condition, hence the output is `"0 20"`, then `i` is incremented and `j` is decremented, thus the output should be `"1 19"` but the next output is `"1 20"`, as if the `j` hasn't been decremented!. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `i==0`, `i++ && j--` [short-circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the first time it is called, so you end up with `i==1` and `j==20`.

You can fix this by using the comma operator: `i++, j--`.

Remember, in C/C++, 0 is considered false, so `0 && x` will never evaluate `x` since it knows the expression is false. See the above link for more detail.

Comment: why does it short circuits? how can i modify the code so that I can print the desired output?

Comment: @user3051238 Replace `i++ && j--` with `i++, j--`.

Answer (score 3):

The expression (i++ && j++) short circuits, and J is never incremented, because (i) holds a (false) initial value.  I think you want it to look more like this:

```
    for (int k=0; i<10 && j > 10; i++, j--)
```

The && operator checks the left side first for truth, and if it's false, (when i is 0, this is false) it doesn't even evaluate the right side.  If the left side IS true, then and ONLY then will it check the right side of the &&.
The incremental part of the for-loop shouldn't be evaluating a boolean condition.